# Usage of istreambuf_iterator<TCHAR>

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a piece of code that reads the content of a .txt-file into a string.

```
std::ifstream file("address.txt");  
std::string oldAddress((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Naturally it also works if I use `std::wstring` instead, like this:

```
std::wifstream file("address.txt"); 
std::string oldAddress((std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>());
```

**Here is my question:** Let's say I don't know if Character Set is Unicode or Multi-Byte and I want my code to be general enough to handle both options. Which is the best way to use the istreambuf_iterator in order to get the string concept based on `TCHAR` ?

This is my attempt, which works, but I wonder if it really is neccessary to create these typedefs.

```
typedef std::basic_ifstream<TCHAR> tifstream;
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR, std::char_traits<TCHAR>, std::allocator<TCHAR>> tstring;

tifstream file("address.txt");  
tstring oldAddress((std::istreambuf_iterator<TCHAR>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<TCHAR>());
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless you need to support extremely old versions of Windows, it's much much less hassle to use wide strings with the API.

Comment: `std::basic_string` has a few default template parameters, so you only need to specify it as `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`. As below, I'd strongly advise against this very approach though.

Comment: Using `TCHAR` in this case is wrong. The external file *address.txt* has its own encoding, that is independent of the project settings producing the executable image. Using `TCHAR` creates an artificial relationship, that simply isn't there. It's one of those things that you have to know. If the external file is using ASCII/UTF-8, use `ifstream`. If it's encoded using UTF-16, use `wifstream`.

Comment: That doesn't work, @IInspectable. You can well read UTF-8 into a wchar_t string or read UTF-16 into a char string. I think that the usual behaviour of a wfstream is to write one byte per character, i.e. a degenerate conversion, though that might have changed with C++11.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for the reply. I think you are on point here, and I was a bit confused. I will stick to 1 bit chars for this project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to handle a new character Type which is not supported out of the box by your library (in this case it is the MSVCRT), apart from the regular typedefs to relate with your character Type, you should also provide a char_traits.

char_traits for your character type is important in absence of which compare, length and other routines statically specialized for the character would not work and you would face undesired behaviour.

Ensure that you specialize your char_traits template for TCHAR

```
template<>
struct char_traits<TCHAR>
{
```

Comment: you need to add a `template<>` above `struct...` when specializing, but otherwise good answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I wouldn't bother with `TCHAR` unless interfacing with the win32 API. In that case then, I'd also just use the wchar_t interfaces of the win32 API and prefer using `wchar_t` in general when handling text internally, in order to be able to support multiple scripts at the same time. Also, wchar_t equals `WCHAR` which is the internal character type of MS Windows using a UTF-16 encoding. Note though that using UTF-16 internally also has its problems, because even there a letter can still use multiple Unicode codepoints and a sigle codepoint can still use multiple `wchar_t`elements, which makes substring operations difficult.

Concerning file input, which you didn't ask about but still mentioned in your example code, this is a different thing. Firstly, using `wchar_t` (aka `WCHAR`) with UTF-16 encoding as internal representation for text allows you to read text files with any encoding. However, when reading a file, you need to know the file's encoding, which then allows you to decode it accordingly. Using different internal representations for different file encodings would be the wrong approach.